# How to remove Warnings from system.log?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a module installed and works fine but everyday and also when I save or update a product I get this in my system.log:

```
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/CustomLabel0.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/CustomLabel0.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/local:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/community:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core:/home/xxxx/public_html/lib:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear')  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/Gender.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/Gender.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/local:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/community:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core:/home/xxxx/public_html/lib:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear')  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/Adult.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/Adult.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/local:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/community:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core:/home/xxxx/public_html/lib:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear')  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/SalePrice.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/SalePrice.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/local:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/community:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core:/home/xxxx/public_html/lib:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear')  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/SalePriceEffectiveDateFrom.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/SalePriceEffectiveDateFrom.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/local:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/community:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core:/home/xxxx/public_html/lib:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear')  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/SalePriceEffectiveDateTo.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/SalePriceEffectiveDateTo.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/local:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/community:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core:/home/xxxx/public_html/lib:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear')  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/Brand.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/Brand.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/local:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/community:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core:/home/xxxx/public_html/lib:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear')  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/Color.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/Color.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/local:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/community:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core:/home/xxxx/public_html/lib:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear')  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/Mpn.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/Mpn.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/local:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/community:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core:/home/xxxx/public_html/lib:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear')  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/Gtin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/Gtin.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/local:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/community:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core:/home/xxxx/public_html/lib:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear')  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/Material.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/Material.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/local:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/community:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core:/home/xxxx/public_html/lib:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear')  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/CustomLabel1.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/CustomLabel1.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/local:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/community:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core:/home/xxxx/public_html/lib:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear')  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/Weight.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/Weight.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/local:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/community:/home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core:/home/xxxx/public_html/lib:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear')  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-21T06:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/Attribute/Name.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

The only thing I can find about this is here: [Warning: include(Google/Config.php)](https://github.com/bluevisiontec/GoogleShoppingApi/issues/12)

The developer says this:

**"if everything works these warnings can be ignored.
This is caused by the current implementation of Google ApiClient. It uses its own autoloader, but Magento tries to load the files, too.
You will get similar warnings for some attributes as they have a fallback to the "Default" attribute."**

Which seems correct because everything seems to work.

I was wondering how I could stop the warnings or not have get logged in system.log?

Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: have you installed BlueVisionTec moduel ? can you please share module url or code?

Comment: Yes I have install the BlueVisionTec module from  https://github.com/bluevisiontec/GoogleShoppingApi for a long time and it works great for me but these errors fill up my system.log.  I'm not sure what part of the code is relevant to post.